# Let Django form add class to input in case of error

Tags: css, django, django-forms

I'm using Django 4.2.9 and need a form add an additional class to an input field, in case the validiation failed.

I can already add classes for every case, but I do not know how to do it for the error-case.

```py
class ItemForm(forms.models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ("text", )
        widgets = {
            "text": forms.widgets.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    "placeholder": "Enter a to-do item",
                    "class": "form-control form-control-lg",
                }
            ),
        }
        error_messages = {"text": {"required": EMPTY_ITEM_ERROR}}

    def save(self, for_list):
        self.instance.list = for_list
        return super().save()
```

I'd like to have `class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid"` for the text-input.

```html
<form method="POST" action="/lists/8/">
    <input type="text" name="text" value="Buy wellies" placeholder="Enter a to-do item" class="form-control form-control-lg" required id="id_text">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="vcojkMtz3GeonURczjMwIsbsDPQUbeKgrXrPIxZY4jIJSfuUKKGVgaj7wLQBatsd">                        
    <div class="invalid-feedback"><ul class="errorlist"><li>You&#x27;ve already got this in your list</li></ul></div>
                        
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably in your case when validation fails over ride the *init* in the following way:

class ItemForm(forms.models.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Item
    fields = ("text",)
    widgets = {
        "text": forms.widgets.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "Enter a to-do item",
                "class": "form-control form-control-lg",
            }
        ),
    }
    error_messages = {"text": {"required": EMPTY_ITEM_ERROR}}

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.errors and 'text' in self.errors:
        text_widget = self.fields['text'].widget
        existing_classes = text_widget.attrs.get('class', '')
        text_widget.attrs['class'] = f'{existing_classes} is-invalid'

def save(self, for_list):
    self.instance.list = for_list
    return super().save()
```

This way we add "is-invalid" class on the text input when validation fails. So basically and hopefully this code will check for any erros in the form text fields. If there is we will be "is-invalid"

I think a better approach (I like everything in parts) is to put the error classes in separate methods so depending what else your project does you might reuse them going forward.

Good luck :)

Comment: Overriding the __init__ breaks the validation. But thanks to your idea I could edit my validation-function (in a child class) to modify the classes like you did in __init__. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of job must be done in _post_clean method not init. Cause you initiate the form. First Time without args ItemForm(), and after post request ItemForm(request.POST). When you use in your view :

```
if request.method == "POST":
   myform = ItemForm(request.POST)
   if myform.is_valid():
        [...]
```

With is valid your form will run full_clean. After fields cleaning will be run _post_clean that you can override :

```
class Meta:
    model = Item
    fields = ("text",)
    widgets = {
        "text":  forms.widgets.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "Enter a to-do item",
                "class": "form-control form-control-lg",
            }
        ),
    }
    error_messages = {"text": {"required": EMPTY_ITEM_ERROR}}

def save(self, for_list):
    self.instance.list = for_list
    return super().save()

def clean_text(self):
    [Here your cleaning  field method]

def _post_clean(self):
    super()._post_clean()
    for k,v in self.errors.items():
        self.fields[k].widget.attrs['class'] += 'is-invalid'
    #in This form you Can directly write : self.field['text'].widget.attrs['class'] += 'is-invalid'
```

For more détails of validation :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/validation/

Hope it will help you.